# Why was I banned from Chat again?

Tags: discussion

I feel I have been arbitrarily banned from chat b/c of who I am.

The below comment is very much similar to what I said about a topic that I did not agree on.

[Comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115717/was-there-ever-a-story-that-involved-hicks-and-newt-surviving#comment313644_115717)

> Aah, I see where you're confused. Alien and Aliens are documentaries.
> Alien3 is a **ripe pile of trash** invented for profit. We don't know what
> happened to anyone after aliens because our records of future history
> end there. We'll just have to wait till we catch up with their
> timeline to know the truth
> The poster called out Aliens in a manner that was very similar to waht I said as well.

I said that "floofs suck balls" which is basically saying that I don't like them, [suck balls definition](https://www.wordnik.com/words/suck%20balls)

> Definitions from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike
> License
>
> **v. to be terrible, of extremely poor quality.** Etymologies

. So b/c I disagreed with the the room owner and now I am banned. Is that the way things are done around here? "ripe pile of trash" is very much similar to "suck balls" in regards to saying that something is not good or bad.

I am aware that the "[be nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)" is enforced, but surely I am allowed to say I dislike something without repercussion? I did not insult anyone, nor did I act like a jerk, so why the ban?

**So why am I banned for voicing my opinion on something I don't like?**

I am under the opinion that I am banned b/c I post controversial posts and I was banned b/c a I said something "suck balls".

Down-votes will just cement my position that I am right BTW. More than 10 down-votes and my ban will be reversed.

Comment: You were banned because literally your first action after coming back off of a long ban (for using inappropriate and insulting language) was to go into chat and start using inappropriate and insulting language.

Comment: @Valorum, what insulting language?

Comment: @Valorum, I insulted no-one!

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck_balls - Verb. (Slang, **Vulgar**).

Comment: @Valorum, so tell me who exactly I insulted with that?

Comment: Multiple chat users (7+) flagged your post as offensive. Clearly *they* were offended

Comment: @Valorum, you did not answer the question, "who did I insult", 7 flags just mean 7 people did not like the comment. Per the be nice rule, I have to have insulted someone, but I did not insult anyone.

Comment: *Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid **vulgar** terms and anything sexually suggestive*.

Comment: ***Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.*** - Telling people their posts "*suck balls*" is definitely rude and belittling.

Comment: @Valorum, I did not tell someones post sucked balls, I said that a topic sucked balls, which means I did not insult anyone at all.

Comment: @Valorum, I belittled no-one.

Comment: @Valorum, so being banned is a reason to be banned again? You said that after coming back from a ban I said something and that was a reason for a ban. So being banned is a disadvantage?

Comment: Being suspended serves two purposes: to give the recipient of the suspension time to learn what behaviors are expected of them and to give the community a bit of respite while that (hopefully) happens. (See [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/311001), SE's explanation of suspensions.) The fact that one has been previously suspended is an indication that usual routes to behavior-correction (comments, chat, mod-messages, meta posts) have not worked and that suspension may be the only tool left to achieve either of the two goals. Not a "disadvantage," just evidence.

Comment: @KyloRen Asking for _who_ reported you is a serious sign of belligerance, especially in an environment of anonimity. Rather than question _who_ did this, why don't you ask _yourself_ what you're doing wrong?

Answer (score 26):

> I feel I have been arbitrarily banned from chat b/c of who I am.

No, it's because of **how you behave**. You have been *repeatedly* banned from chat, main, and meta because of your inappropriate, offensive, and inflammatory behaviour, but you never seem to have examined your behaviour or learned your lesson from any of these bans.

> So b/c I disagreed with the the room owner and now I am banned. Is that the way things are done around here?

Not really. If you'd said instead that you don't like floofs, you wouldn't have been banned for it. A basic rule of human interaction is that the *way* you say something can be as important as *what* you say. If you express your opinions in a confrontational and belligerent way using unnecessarily foul language, then you may well find yourself banned for doing so, but you won't be banned simply for expressing your opinions.

> I am under the opinion that I am banned b/c I post controversial posts and I was banned b/c a I said something "suck balls".

That's pretty much right, yes. You make a habit of, as you yourself put it, "stirring shit", which is not a healthy or constructive way to participate in a community. This, together with your tendency to post offensive comments, is more than enough reason to ban someone.

> Down-votes will just cement my position that I am right BTW. More than 10 down-votes and my ban will be reversed.

I don't know how you think this works, but ... it doesn't work like that. If anything, downvotes on meta are more likely to indicate that you're *wrong*, not right, and I can guarantee that nobody is going to reverse your ban because you got downvoted on meta.

> Why was I banned from Chat again?

When you returned to chat after your last ban, this is what happened.

- Your [first message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/40952111/history) was:

  > Why can't I post on meta? I have shit to stir now I am un banned

  Thus demonstrating your bad faith and desire to cause controversy and act like a nuisance as soon as you returned to the site.
- You then continued looking for a fight:

  > 6 month is a long time, the next ban will be even more fun
  >
  > @Skooba, no they(the ominous they) are out to get me. I can't help being hated
  >
  > @TimE.Lord, wtf, who are you? And what is floofs
  >
  > @Skooba, hopefuly I don't get banned for saying "wtf" which is very likely with the current moderating team
  >
  > @TimE.Lord, overlords suck
  >
  > @TimE.Lord, nice, foofs suck balls

  Eventually, after you started to get overtly offensive by using vulgar language, you got the reaction you were looking for: flags and a short suspension from chat.
- A moderator then noticed what was going on. Your abusive behaviour yesterday, combined with your past history of abusive behaviour, caused the decision to ban you from chat for a year. I wasn't the moderator who made this decision, but I wholeheartedly support it. Your inappropriate behaviour has continued for far too long, and you've shown absolutely no sign of learning lessons from your past warnings and bans. Perhaps now your year-long absence from chat will give you time to think over your behaviour and how to improve it.